# More elegant (shorter) solution for this regex pattern

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have spent three days banging my head on how to find a single solution to match anything between either single or double quotes with escaped single or doublequotes within actual source string and to replace matching text .. and I think that I have succeeded. Multi-line or single-line - it works. That is, this regex can be used to alter/change/sanitize `'text'` or `"text"` or strings in other words, in any source code *(eg: `file_get_contents ('some_class.php')`) and to leave everything else untouched, assuming that code comments are already removed before such action.

Here is regex wrapped in singlequotes ..

```
'@"[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*"|\'[^\'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\'\\\\]*)*\'@msu'
```

.. and here is regex wrapped within doublequotes.

```
"@\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\"|'[^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*'@msu"
```

It is perfeclty matching with source code like this ...

```php
// Very nasty php array 

$Damn = [

  'a' => "' lorem ipsum '",

  'b' => '"\" ipsu\'m lorem  ',

  'c' => " \' YabadabaDooya \" ",

  'd\"' => ' 

     f"

     o\'"o  

                 \'bar" ',

  'e' => "'",

  "f" => '"'

];
```

Since this is working as I expect, and I am actually not a PCRE guru (don't ask how much 'pain' I've had in the past three days D: until I came up to this solution), if there's anyone who knows how, and is willing to help by shrinking the above regex into more elegant/shorter solution, that would be superb. I assume that `|` (or) in the middle of the pattern can be placed onto beginning, just once .. and I tried **God only knows what** .. to accomplish that, but no luck.

So, the general question is - how would shorter variant of the above pattern look alike ?

Comment: `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'` uses 2 unrolled loop segments separated by OR. If that works, then that is ideal already. As to what you're trying to match, I don't know. https://regex101.com/r/l4siRL/1 and https://regex101.com/r/SxXVIA/1

Comment: `(["'])((?:\\\1|(?:(?!\1)).)*)(\1)` https://regex101.com/r/G9LEoz/1 I hope this helps

Comment: @WahyuKristianto - Since your regex undo's the unrolled loop construct and introduces an alternation inside of a quantified group along with indirect addressing backreferences, the performance is slowed bt a factor of 20.

Comment: @WahyuKristianto: it's indeed shorter, but it's less efficient than a two branch pattern (one for double and one for single quotes).

Comment: Your two patterns are perfect don't try to change them. Even if they look a bit long, they are efficient because PCRE is able to optimize patterns when each branch starts with a literal character (only position in the subject string with these characters are tested, instead of all positions in the string).

Comment: Yes, simply would be more difficult. I take my hat off for @sln answer :beer:

Comment: If you want something more "elegant", use the x modifier (freespace mode). You can also put your pattern in a NOWDOC string to avoid many backslashes. As an aside the m modifier is useless.

Comment: Note that if you are dealing with php source code, You can use `token_get_all`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - There's even better *(which I use to sanitize comments of all kind + simple strings) which is `PhpToken::Tokenize ($filecontents)` .. ;)

Comment: @Spooky: never used it but it looks handy.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - It is a new thing in php8. As they say, much faster than `token_get_all()` and You get object for each and every token generated. BlYAtiful. :)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte -  So, let's get back to the topic .. You think that changing the regex I came up is not a good option .. ? I do care for performance, all the time, to be honnest.

Comment: @Spooky: Yes, but to avoid ugly things, you can write it like this; https://3v4l.org/f5vuU

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte  - Please, don't get me wrong, but I do know how to pack ugly strings in php in numerous of ways :) Here, this is also neat .. https://3v4l.org/X4hWT#v8.1.2 .. anyway, should I change `msu` to `sux` as You proposed in Your ___3v4l___ example .. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Spooky, try this Multi-Delimiter Common Core approach
which is mostly your regex.

```
<<<PCRE

    (["'`])((?:\\.|(?!\1|\\).)*)(\1)

PCRE;
```

https://regex101.com/r/LLWa6L/1

```
<<<PCRE_EXPLAINED

     ( ["'`] )              # (1), The delimiters
     (                      # (2 start)
        (?:
           \\ .                   # Escape anything
         |                       # or,
           (?! \1 | \\ )          # Not a delimiter nor an escape
           .                      # Any character
        )*
     )                      # (2 end)
     ( \1 )                 # (3), Backreference to the delimiter

PCRE_EXPLAINED;
```

Comment: That approach wasn't mine. :)

Comment: Pretty much your last regex just a subtle change .

Comment: That was last regex in my last post, but the idea for regex format is not mine. :) Therefore, not mine, but from this guy https://stackoverflow.com/users/984422/wahyu-kristianto

Comment: @Spooky - It's not a novel idea. Fact is it's used as a first thought in a naive way to do it. It's a novice's approach that some try to point out has many conceptual errors and pitfalls. Doesn't matter if it works on some sample, it has to work on all. I posted a version of _your_ regex that is _fixed_. As I mentioned in the Question comment about that approach: `Since your regex undo's the unrolled loop construct and introduces an alternation inside of a quantified group along with indirect addressing backreferences, the performance` after all fixes are slowed by 100 times.

Comment: @Spooky - One other thing to note, if you are parsing language text that use these quote rules, you must parse the language comments at the same time as they may contain embedded quotes. Also, these must be valid source text that have been compiled/interpreted without any _string termination_ errors. Notably, the evenness of quotes regex can be used as a preliminary valid string test  instead.

Comment: @sin, how old are you ? I am 42. And I have 15+ years of programming/coding experience. Do you really think that comments, C-shell style and block comments were not considered, already handled before this .. in production ? I understand your effort to be helpful, and I appreciate it really .. I really do, but for God's sake PLEASE! .. just read the first introductionary post I made in the first question .. I don't want to cite my self. Please, just do that.

Comment: @sin .. now, assuming that You did that, think like this: thanks to You, and Your post and Wahyu's two cents and my approach .. we now have three valid, working solutions for the task. :) Isn't that wonderful thing ? :) Appart from that, how did You test performance ? If it is from the regex101, I can tell You that it's innacurate.

Comment: I am not saying that You are speaking nonsenses, no, I can see that You just trying to be helpful. But I am curious, where did the performance measurements came from .. ? Which platform as well ? Quite important if You ask me.

Comment: ps: forgive me as I misspelled Your nick. It's not sin but sln .. :s damn.

Comment: @Spooky - I use class `CHiResTimer` which encapsulates `QueryPerformanceCounter(LARGE_INTEGER *p)` which is a high resolution (<1us) time stamp microsecond counter.

Comment: Oh, ok. cpp. It counts. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final (this time, really) answer to this problem/topic. In my previous post (that I deleted) I wrote that answer from [Wahyu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984422/wahyu-kristianto) was the perfect one, but due to my natural lack of patience, that wasn't quite true (there's no such thing as "too much testing"), as further tests showed some innacuracy. Anyway, I still claim that Wahyu's approach - IS - the one that I was looking for and with just a tiny bit of modification, this time, I have succeeded in what I wanted.

Here's the original proposal by Wahyu that spared and saved my time - **a lot!**.

```php
<<<REGEX

    (["'])((?:\\\1|(?:(?!\1)).)*)(\1)


REGEX;
```

But that regex fails with something like this ...

```php
    
  $ArrayWithCorrectSyntaxButIdioticStrings = [
    

    'a' => 'C:\\',

    'b' => "D:\\",
    
    'c' => " This i\s '
      '
      \'
      ' not a 
      ' 
      \" love song"
    

  ];
```

It failed on both 'a' and 'b' => values, meaning -> `'\\'`

But, with just a bit of modification, it truly became a - CHARM.

Here's the golden expression :)

- Literal Variant (for online testing, etc.) nothing escaped.

```php
<<<REGEX

    (["'`])((?:\\.[\1]*|(?:(?!\1)).)*)(\1)

REGEX;
```

^^ for `regex101.com` tests **gmus** modifiers are required.

- And a simple string variant that safely can go into production:

```php
    $regex = '@(["\'`])((?:\\\\.[\\1]*|(?:(?!\\1)).)*)(\\1)@usm';
```

And here's my own primary solution that also works correctly, maybe even more performant, but that I find ugly like a bI4tch. D:

```
    $regex = '@"[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*"'
        . '|\'[^\'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\'\\\\]*)*\''
        . '|`[^`\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^`\\\\]*)*`'
        . '@usm';
```

---

To summarize everything ...

Both regexes will find and match any text that is wrapped within backticks (php shell execution), singlequotes and doublequotes in one shot.

Tested over 15+ files that have over 2000 or 3000 lines of code (on Debian 10 with PHP 8.1 built-in web server).

Ideal for extracting or modifying strings over any source code file that uses single, doublequotes or backticks for string values/commands.

The main key difference is that Wahyu's proposal can be adjusted on just one place (1st capturing group), while my solution would take a bit more adjusting.

---

**Edit:**

After a while and/or in the meantime, as it seems like there's no point in looking for more solutions, as there are three valid variants, and the appropriate answer from [sln](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15577665/sln) been accepted, this question no longer falls into category for discussion.

Comment: Your regex `(["'\`])((?:\\.[\1]*|(?:(?!\1)).)*)(\1)` matches `'\'jk\'`" https://regex101.com/r/aRqLMp/1

Comment: Just checked .. no it doesn't. You need to include **gmsu** modifiers. With just **gu** it fails.

Comment: You checked the demo link I posted ?

Comment: No, they are not irrelevant. Yes, I have checked both demo links.

Comment: I believe You maybe have a trouble with coloring on regex101 D: It's all good.

Comment: And yes .. it indeed is interesting. Quite useful in first place.

Comment: Ok I'll post it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241846/discussion-between-spooky-and-sln).